# Mixed model development structure

Tags: r, mixed-model

My boss believes the data that we are working with might be understood via a mixed model. I wanted to make sure I was designing the model correctly as well as having a couple of questions.

We have data from an old and new machine, that had samples split between the two for each animal. The samples result in different values (thus the reason to try and see the difference and how we can correct it). He wants to have a mixed model with the machine being a fixed effect and each animal as a random effect with each of the 100 cells measured for that animal to be nested inside animal as a random effect while compared to the measurements that are out put by the machine (ie. VAP).

I currently have combined the data into one data.frame so it looks like this `lm=lmerTest::lmer(VAP ~ Machine + (1|ID/Cell), data=df)`. He also wants to have the "estimate" and other values given by summary() for each of the two machines but when I get the summary for this I only get them as a combined value, and couldn't find anything on the internet about this.

I have tried separating each machine as a data.frame as well but with or without Machine as a variable I get "Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations."

Am I building the model correctly and how do I get the separated estimates?

Edit:
After talking with my boss it seems to us that the output from the first model is basically a saying that Machine 1 has an Estimate of 80.465 and Machine 2 would have estimate of 77.158 (80.465-3.307).

Here is the outputs from both of the models for reference.
[image: "From the model previously outlined"]

[image: "From the model with -1"]

Comment: Have you tried lm=lmerTest::lmer(VAP ~ -1 + Machine + (1|ID/Cell), data=df)?  Eliminating the intercept from your model by using -1 should give you what you need.  Currently, you are getting the difference in mean VAP values between the two machines.  Eliminating the intercept will give you the mean VAP value for each machine.

Comment: I still only get Machine and not a breakdown of it. I also have Cell with a 0 Varience, not sure if that is because they are just numbered 1-100 or something else.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what goes on without seeing the R output. Can you post the model output here (you can change your numbers slightly if need be).